# Azure nodejs function: do I have to pass the "Context" parameter all the way down to be able to do console log?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

In Azure Nodejs Function, there is a `Context` object that serves as input parameter to the invoked function:

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions";
import { workerExec } from "./services/worker";

const workerFunction: AzureFunction = async function (
  context: Context,
  req: HttpRequest
): Promise<void> {
  let result;
  try {
    result = await workerExec(req, context);

  } catch (error) {
    context.log("Failed on workerExec()");
    context.log(error);
    throw error;
  }

  context.res = {
    body: result,
  };
};
```

The `workerExec` function is migrated from a Non Azure function environment. It has many functions / nested functions and `console.log()` lines.

It seems that in Azure function we have to use `context.log` instead of `console.log`.

Do I have to pass the `context` object down each function in order to replace the `console.log` function and preserve the logs ?

It seems so weird and it makes a lot of "parameter drilling" in the code.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to pass the `context` object down each function in order to replace the `console.log` function and preserve the logs ?

Yes, it is recommended to use `context.log` to write logs in azure functions as per this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=javascript%2Cwindows%2Cazure-cli&pivots=nodejs-model-v3#logging).

*This [Ms document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=javascript%2Cwindows%2Cazure-cli&pivots=nodejs-model-v3#logging) also says the below-*

> If you use the alternative Node.js `console.log` method, those logs are tracked at the app-level and will *not* be associated with any specific function. It is *highly recommended* to use `context` for logging instead of `console` so that all logs are associated with a specific function.

You can refer to this [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54831728/context-log-vs-console-log-in-azure-function-apps) as well.